# ASP.Net MVC 5 Selecting muliple items in a listbox on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox

Wrapping my head around MVC.

I have a list of items. I need to load the screen with some of these selected by default.

Loading the items is one thing, trying to select some by default isn't working for me.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

I know there are many answers to a similar question, though I can't seem to translate the answers to my needs.

Here is the code I have, and tried - i am also trying to understand the various options in the html helpers. Please take this into consideration when posting a solution.

This is the most recent iteration of my code; i have gone through a bunch....

In my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Statuses = AddStatuses();
    return View();
}


private MultiSelectList AddStatuses()
{
    string[] defaultSelected = { "Ready", "Done", "Error" };
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<Status> s = allTypes.GetStatuses();
    s.ForEach(status =>
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = status.Name,
            Value = status.ID.ToString(),
            Selected = true,// defaultSelected.Contains(status.Name)
        });
    });
    return new MultiSelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text");
}
```

In an attempt to test my defaultSelected.Contains, i just commented it out to select ALL as true... still didn't work...

I have tried these in my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Statuses", null, null, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = true, id="queueStatuses" })

@Html.ListBox("Name", ViewBag.Statuses as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "queueStatuses" })

@Html.ListBox("Statuses", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "queueStatuses" })
```

I a) don't understand what i am doing and b) can't get it to work... :)

I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Shyju. I am sure your answer works.

As mentioned in my comments though, I don't want to go through the hoops of having a view model in this instance. I was looking for a simple way to implement this.

Seems all i needed to do was change my `MultiSelectList` and pass in an array of selected 'value's.

This fixes my issue:

```
private MultiSelectList AddStatuses()
        {
            string[] defaultSelected = { "3", "5", "6" };
            List<SelectListItem> allItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<Status> s = allTypes.GetStatuses();
            s.ForEach(status =>
            {
                allItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = status.Name,
                    Value = status.ID.ToString(),
                });
            });
            return new MultiSelectList(allItems, "Value", "Text", defaultSelected);
        }
```

And my `ListBox` is the same. Went with this one in the end:

```
 @Html.ListBox("status", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Statuses, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ListBoxFor` helper method along with the user of a view model to pass the items for your list box.

So create a new view model to transfer data from your action method to view

```
public class CreateIssue
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Statuses { set;get;}
  public int[] SelectedStatuses { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, load the `Statuses` collection and send it to the view. If you want to preselect some items, set the `SelectedStatuses` property.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new CreateIssue();
  //Hard coded for demo. You may replace with values coming from db table.
  vm.Statuses = new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Ready"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Done"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text="Building"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="4", Text="Error"},
  };
  //For preselecting items, set it here
  vm.SelectedStates=new int[] { 2,3};
  return View(vm);
}
```

and your in your view, which is strongly typed to the view model, use the `ListBoxFor` helper method.

```
@model CreateIssue
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Select many statuses</label>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStatuses, Model.Statuses)   
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: How can i get it to work with the ViewBag - rather not use a viewmodel here; i am going to be using Ajax on the page so the whole viewmodel isn't required - and WOW that is a whole lot to just select some default items....

Comment: How does view model affects an ajax method ?

Comment: it doesn't really, but i am aiming to keep this simple. Your code, though i am sure works, requires more than i believe is needed to just  to load a list box with a bunch of values and have some pre-selected. Also (i am new with MVC) you have your ActionResult Create - what is this and how would it be called? I have an index action. Is that not the one my controller is calling? how is this create action called?

Comment: Just change the Create action method to Index.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Figured what i was missing, so didn't have to change much.